# Convert Rockwell ACD PLC files to L5X files (similar to xml file's structure)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, converters

Is there any way that we can convert an ACD PLC files from Rockwell to L5X PLC files automatically instead of going through the RSLogix app and convert them manually? Since the ACD files are unreadable, so I would like to change them to L5X files, which is readable and in xml structure, to parse their information. However, I'm having a list of files and can't do them manually every time. It would be great if there might be a way to do them in Python script.

I have tried looking through sources but not finding one currently

Answer (score 0):

factory talk hub has a vault module where acd can be stored and downloaded in bulk in different formats
(requires a rockwell account)
https://home.cloud.rockwellautomation.com/dashboard

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35187221)